# Destructor called unexpectedly

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

Why is the destructor `~TestClass()` in this simple code called twice?

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class TestClass
{
  int m_val;

public:
  TestClass(int val);
  ~TestClass();
};

TestClass::TestClass(int val) : m_val(val)
{
  std::cout << this << " TestClass() " << m_val << "\n";
}

TestClass::~TestClass()
{
  std::cout << this << " ~TestClass() " << m_val << "\n";
  m_val = -1;
}

int main()
{
  auto x = std::make_unique<TestClass>(2);

  auto y = *x;  // <<<< this triggers it
}
```

Output

```
000001E66C0B5980 TestClass() 2
00000057FDD9FAB4 ~TestClass() 2   // why is the destructor called here?
000001E66C0B5980 ~TestClass() 2
```

Comment: Because you have two objects. You didn't see the second constructor call because you didn't instrument the copy constructor (there's also the move constructor, but adding a custom copy constructor will remove it, so instrumenting the copy constructor is enough to not miss any objects).

Comment: There are two instances; the one created by `make_unique` and `y`.

Comment: what did you expect `auto y = *x;` to do ?

Comment: `y` is a copy of `*x` so then `y` is destructed and `*x` right after.

Comment: This is a clear violation of **rule 0/3/5** for **RAII**. In this case you should follow **rule 3**. Because you have defined a **destructor**, you have to provide a **copy constructor** as well as the **copy assignment operator**. The accepted answer is missing the later, hence it is wrong. For staters you should implement rule 3 via **copy/swap idiom**.

Comment: Note that [copy and swap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3279543/4581301) is not always the optimal `operator=` solution, but it is extremely simple and nearly foolproof. That makes it a fantastic starting point, and profiling will tell you if you need a more complicated solution.

Comment: @Red.Wave The question is not about any violation. It is about why no dtor call. Any logical error in the code is not my responsibility to solve.

Comment: @user4581301 it works for beginners and produces correct code. Optimization is not the primary objective. A fully optimized solution might follow rule 5 instead of 3.

Comment: @user12002570 you must be prepared to accept critics, specially when giving comments before doing enough research.

Comment: @Red.Wave No, there is no need to point out additonal logical problems(if any) with the code. They can be added to answer but that is purely additional and optional to the original problem. You should not judge an answer based on whether the answer point out those additional/options problems in their answer when the answer specifically point out the problem that the OP is asking about.

Comment: There's only one logic problem: the one you missed.

Comment: @Red.Wave Also it seems like you missed the point. This is a `TestClass` which is written for reproducing the specific problem on stackoveflow and not to solve any additonal problems that it may have. A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is create for such purposes only instead of reviewing the code to make it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `auto y = *x;`  // <<<< this triggers it

The above is **copy initialization** and would use copy constructor of the class. The extra destructor call that you're seeing is corresponding to this object `y`. You can also verify this by adding a copy ctor to your class and you'll notice that the copy ctor is used to create `y` using `*x`.

```
class TestClass
{
  int m_val;

public:
  TestClass(int val);
  ~TestClass();
   //added this copy ctor
  TestClass(const TestClass &p): m_val(p.m_val)
//-------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--->use member initializer list
  {
      std::cout << this << " copy ctor " << m_val << "\n";
  }
};
//other code as before
```

Comment: `TestClass z {3}; z=y;` and boom. You fail again. `3` is never destructed.

Comment: @Red.Wave The question is not about any violation. It is about why no dtor call. Any logical error in the code is not my responsibility to solve.

Comment: It is obvious that you need to learn **RAII** too. You're solution is violating the **rule 0/3/5**; in short words it's wrong. The answer should provide enough information on the source of problem, and yours just doesn't. Because you didn't know the real problem yourself. End of discussion.

Comment: @Red.Wave No it is not my responsibility to solve all the problems in the world or someone else's code. They are solely responsible for their code. I do no account for anyone else's mistakes. I only point out the problem that was specifically asked in the question which is why no dtor call. You cannot blame your mistakes on me. You can atmost suggest a link to [the rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) to OP.

Comment: It is your responsibility not to spread missinformation but to mention correct answers. You cannot of course mention things you've not mastered yet; that's when someone corrects you.

Comment: @Red.Wave Also it seems like you missed the point. This is a `TestClass` which is written specifically for reproducing the specific problem at hand on stackoveflow and not to solve any additonal problems that it may have. A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is create for such purposes only instead of reviewing the code to make it better.

Comment: It is an example of wrong code, due to insufficient information. Stop spamming please.

Comment: @Red.Wave No, defending your point of view wherever needed is not spamming. And your assumption that I don't know RAII is wrong. Just because someone don't show everything they know by making OP's code the best possible version available on the market/world/site, doesn't mean they don't know that concept. This is not a "make this code the best performance wise or production wise" site. Also OP not even asked to make their code better.